# Access the content of browser extension popup window

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to access the content of the popup window from the browser extension using javascript from my site. My purpose is to listen to if a button is clicked from the popup window. How can this be achieved?

Comment: How is the popup window opened?

Comment: With a third party library

Comment: That _third-party library_ still needs to use some technique or method in the DOM API for creating that popup, and that's what matters. So, through which specific DOM API or technique is the popup being created?

Comment: So it's a react app...and the popup is opened inside the npm library...that's why I can't get the reference to the popup directly...I am thinking there is  a generic way to listen for an browser extension window is popped up and grab it's content.

Comment: Hold on, is the pop up being created by a browser extension or the webpage? The difference matters. You contradicted yourself there.